# Quickly/Glade autoadjust text position

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygtk, glade

In Quickly/Glade, is it possible to keep the text (well, labels) centered, so when I maximize my program's window, the text stays centered? It's probably something easy to do, but I have been unable to find where to auto-adjust the position. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to ask this at http://stackoverflow.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is caused by how you are creating your layout. It sounds like you are using a fixed layout (as your top-level layout) which will make it much more difficult to do.

The best thing to do is to create a fluid layout by starting your layout with a GtkBox within your GtkWindow. Much like this:

[image: window -> box -> label]

This will make your layout fluid and allow for your text to become centered within your window. If you have to remain with a fixed layout, you'll have to attempt to center the label problematically.

If you are using a GridLayout, I believe you'll need to turn on "Horizontal Expand" on the label to get it to fill the unused cell space. However, its been awhile, so don't hold me to that.

Comment: You are correct, and that does work nicely :D.